# Cannot add a comment using Safari on iPad1 iOS 5.1.1

Tags: support, comments

The add comment button seems to do nothing, rendering it impossible to comment on a question. iPad 1, latest possible iOS for hardware 5.1.1, using Safari. Perhaps the functionality has changed for commenting in certain scenarios?

The button just does not respond.  This feature certainly used to work on this machine, but perhaps SO has changed the functionality or a bug has crept in.

I did not add the bug tag, I would rather await confirmation that it is indeed a bug from the developers or closer associates

Comment: Works fine for me on IOS 9.2

Comment: Thanks Martin - will try to clear all caches on Safari.  Reboot didn't help (using a PC now)

Comment: iPad1 and 5.1.1 are notoriously awful.  iOS 4.3 was much better. Anyway, this Definitely still does not work - after full cache drop and reboot - still the Add Comment button does nothing on the iPad (This is a PC)

Comment: @MartinSmith - If I could run iOS 9.2 on this dinosaur I would :)

Comment: And you can't update Safari itself any further? (probably not, app developers are only encouraged to support the previous and current generation of iOS). I wonder if it is possible to see console errors on an iPad, it is probably reporting a javascript error that could be useful to the stack development team. The site might need a polyfill for ancient versions of Safari.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks I will see if I can get some debug information from this old thing.  I don't think Safari can be updated further on this iPad. (Commenting using a PC)